# Как получить информацию из объекта класса, не создавая новый экземпляр?

Tags: java, классы

Есть три класса: `A`, `B`, `C`.

Класс `А` создает объект класса `С`, чтобы получить значения:

```
public class A() 
{
    С sdf = new C();
    sdf.getA; ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Класс `C` хранит значения и методы:

```
public class C()
{
    private int a = 10;

    public void method() 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Как в классе `B` получить те же данные из класса `C`?

Если, я создаю новый класс,

```
public class B() 
{
    C dfg = new C();
}
```

то создаётся новый объект, и, соответственно, значения уже другие...

Comment: класс C всегда должен быть в одном экземпляре? Может тогда singleton (или аналоги) использовать? Тогда без разницы откуда вы его (класс C) получать будете - данные всегда будут одними и теми же

Comment: @OgneFF а что значит "значения уже другие"? У вас каждый раз при создании экземпляра С полю "а" присваивается значение 10. Или вы думаете, что для каждого экземпляра это будет какое-то своё десять? Десять - оно и в Африке десять

Comment: @DreamChild это просто пример, на деле у меня эта а - число динамическое и каждый раз меняется. И мне надо в классе А и В работать с ним, но создавая новый объект, мы работаем с другим объектом, понимаешь?

Comment: @BOPOH поподробнее насчет singleton, пожалуйста)

Comment: Чтобы получить что-то из класса не создавая экземпляр класса, то это про static методы и поля класса, можно почитать тут: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html Только я не уверен, что это подойдет вам потому что я не знаю как вы потом взаимодействуете с этим полем.

Comment: Хочу создать вспомогательный класс, в котором будут поля и методы. 
Суть какая: есть класс, который описывает завод, кол-во рабочих, что производят и с каким качеством - это класс А,  есть другой завод, в котором поля и методы те же, а цифры другие(к примеру рабочих меньше) - это класс B. Я делаю сейчас события - методы, которые влияют на поля завода (случайная смерть ит.д.), но хранить эти методы я хочу не в классах завода, а в отдельный собрать класс, потому что есть еще, к примеру, школы, в которых тоже события, но они отличаются от заводских. И ВСЯ ПРОБЛЕМА В ПРАВИЛЬНОМ ДОСТУПЕ К КЛАССУ

Comment: Очевидно проблемы не с доступом к классу, а с непониманием ООП, что такое класс, что такое экземпляр класса и т.д. Хорошо если кто-нибудь сумеет на пальцах объяснить или дать ссылку на хорошую макулатурку для ... чайников. Вот например http://avolberg.ru/theory/oop Мельком глянул, за качество и правдивость не ручаюсь

Comment: «...это класс А, есть другой завод, в котором поля и методы те же, а цифры другие(к примеру рабочих меньше) - это класс B.» — вам определенно нужно почитать что-нибудь по основам ООП. То, что вы описываете, требует двух экземпляров (объектов) одного класса, но никак не двух классов. На то и нужны классы, чтобы один раз описывать структуру однотипных объектов.

Comment: @BOPOH: похоже, не в синглтонах тут дело. Прочитайте остальные комментарии )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
b.dfg = a.sdf;
```

Если ты хочешь, чтобы во всех экземплярах классов A и B sdf и dfg были одинаковы, то sdf и dfg должны быть static;

```
public class A() 
{
    static С sdf = new C();
}

public class B() 
{
    static С dfg = new C();
}
```

и тогда, чтобы получить sdf и dfg, не нужно будет создавать экземпляры классов A и B, достаточно будет обратиться

```
A.sdf.method();
B.dfg.method();
```

А лучше опиши свою задачу, может стоит как-то иначе сделать.

Comment: В классе C хранится это значение, мне не принципиально создавать новые объекты классов, мне важно получить это значение для класса A и B, любыми способами

Comment: тогда просто присвой B.dfg значение A.sdf

Comment: Нет, так не получится сделать. Смотри, надо, чтобы любые поля и методы класса C были доступны классу A и B. Но чтобы они были доступны надо создать объект класса C (С name = new C();). В этом то и проблема, что создавать придется и в А и в В. Других способов я не знаю..

Answer (score 1):

Создавайте экземпляр класса С не в конструкторе, а где-то извне, а в конструктор классов A или B передавайте один и тот же экземпляр с одним и тем же внутренним состоянием. Тем более, что создавая внутри одного класса экземпляр другого, вы получаете нежелательную связанность этих классов друг с другом. В идеале конструктор A или B должен принимать даже не класс, а некий интерфейс, реализацией которого будет класс С. Тем самым у вас исчезнет прямая зависимость между A и С и между B и С

Comment: даа)) я тоже так считаю, что нужно создать его в отдельности, чтобы доступ был для всех одинаковый. НО КАК?!  Я просто не знаю..Да, я могу загуглить, найти что либо, но я не знаю, что искать)) Я не знаю, чего я не знаю) 
Если пример напишешь самый простой, то будет очень здорово :)

Comment: @OgneFF эммм...вы не умеете создавать экземпляры классов?

Comment: Уважаемый, вопрос вроде нормально поставлен, если нет, то спроси, что не понятно. Ты дал мне ответ, который теоретически я понимаю как сделать, но на практике никогда не сталкивался, поэтому и прошу мне самый простой пример. Так что либо помоги, либо не задавай глупых вопросов

Comment: Смотри, надо, чтобы любые поля и методы класса C были доступны классу A и B. Но чтобы они были доступны надо создать объект класса C (С name = new C();). В этом то и проблема, что создавать придется и в А и в В. Других способов я не знаю..Какие есть идеи?

Comment: @OgneFF, `c= new C(); a = new A(c); b=new B(c)` примерно так

Answer (score 0):

Может вам подойдет такой вариант:

```
class A {
    private C sdf = new C();

    private A() {}

    public A(C sdf) {
        this.sdf = sdf;
    }

    public C getSdf() {
        return sdf;
    }
}

class B {
    private C sdf = new C();

    private B() {}

    public B(C sdf) {
        this.sdf = sdf;
    }

    public C getSdf() {
        return sdf;
    }
}

class C {
    private int a = 10;

    public void method() {

    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c = new C();
        A a = new A(c);
        B b = new B(c);
    }
}
```

Поля и методы класса `C` можно проксировать в классах `A` и `B`, если есть такая необходимость.

Answer (score -2):

Сделать переменную (и метод доступа к ней) статическими. Если разные пакеты, то еще и добавить модификатор доступа public (к методу или переменной).
Доступ из классов А и В будет выглядеть как то так С.имя_переменная или С.getИмяМетода

Comment: Класс с состоянием – идея далеко не всегда хорошая. Открывать поля в public — тоже.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Для получения одних и тех же данных подойдет использование статической переменной т.к. одна одна для всех инстансов и я думаю это самый подходящий способ для данной задачи.

"Открывать поля в public — тоже." — открыть можно метод. Что больше подходит